# ERROR: MissingComponentException

Tags: unity, c#

I want my gameObject to play an audio clip when it collides with other gameObjects. So I attached a script named "ImpactSound" with it, but it's keep showing MissingComponentException: There is no "AudioSource" attatched to the ball(clone)game object, but a script is trying to accept it.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class ImpactSound : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioClip impact;
    AudioSource source;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnCollisionEnter2D() {
    Debug.Log ("Sound was supposed to play on collision!");
    source.PlayOneShot (impact);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you attached an AudioSource component to the game object?

Comment: Yes I've attached an audio clip on impact..@Tyyppi_77

Comment: That's not what I asked. Is there a **AudioSource** component in the object?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you don't have an Audio Source attached with that following game object. [image: Audio Source]

Comment: Well, that worked. But now I want to make it sound only when it collides with a specific gameObject. How am I supposed to do so?

Comment: The `PlayOnAwake` is surely checked. Uncheck it.

Comment: @Jatin, use tag to that game object. Its quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

The RequireComponent attribute automatically adds required components as dependencies.

> When you add a script which uses RequireComponent to a GameObject, the
>   required component will automatically be added to the GameObject. This
>   is useful to avoid setup errors. For example a script might require
>   that a AudioSource is always added to the same GameObject. Using
>   RequireComponent this will be done automatically, thus you can never
>   get the setup wrong. Note that RequireComponent only checks for
>   missing dependencies during the moment the component is added to a
>   GameObject. Existing instances of the component whose GameObject lacks
>   the new dependencies will not have those dependencies automatically
>   added.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent (typeof (AudioSource))]
public class ImpactSound : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip impact;
    AudioSource source;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        source.clip = impact;
    }

    // when collide with other with tag enemy play sound
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            source.PlayOneShot(impact);
        }
    }
}
```

other way for prevent missing error that checking object have AudioSource component.in this example I use Property for checking it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ImpactSound : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip impact;
    AudioSource source
    {
        get
        {
            if (GetComponent<AudioSource>() == null)
            {
                gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
                return GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            }else
            {
                return GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            }
        }
        set
        {
                source.clip = impact;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            source.PlayOneShot(impact);
        }
    }
}
```

if you don't like have error you can use AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint , in this way your object Instantiate empty gameObject with AudioSource component in position that is easy way for play sound.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ImpactSound : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip impact;

    // when collide with something play sound
    void OnCollisionEnter2D()
    {
            Debug.Log("Sound was supposed to play on collision!");
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(impact, transform.position);
    }
}
```